# Find the minimum value of $\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{2b+1}+\sqrt{3c+1}$ if $a+b+c=1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a,b,c\ge 0$, and $a+b+c=1$. Find the minimum value of
> $$\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{2b+1}+\sqrt{3c+1}$$

I think the minimum value is $\sqrt{2} + 2$? when $a=1,b=c=0$.

Of course, I can't prove it. Can anyone help?

Comment: Should the middle term be $\sqrt{2b + 1}$?  Also for the title.  Now, are you looking for an arithmetic proof, or a proof using some Cal 3 techniques?  The latter will undoubtedly be much easier, if that's admissible for you.

Comment: @1110101001,$a,b,c\ge 0$

Comment: Is it not clear that for all positive value of $a$ the expression is greater than 3, so that the minimun is when $a=0$? Are you correct with your question?

Answer (score 2):

The objective function is concave in each of its variables, and the domain is closed and convex. so the minimum will occur when the variables take extreme values allowed. It is easy to see that with the constraint, this is possible when two among $a,b,c$ is zero, and the minimum is $2+\sqrt2$ obtained when $a=1, b=c=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
U=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x+y+z=1\text{ and }x,y,z\ge 0\}\\
S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x+y+z=1\text{ and }x,y,z>0\}.
$$
Define $f,g:U\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{align}
f(a,b,c)&=\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{2b+1}+\sqrt{3c+1}\\
g(a,b,c)&=a+b+c-1,
\end{align}
then
\begin{align}
\nabla f&=\left(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+1}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2b+1}},\frac{3}{2\sqrt{3c+1}}\right)\\
\nabla g&=(1,1,1).
\end{align}
If a local minimum exists in $S$, there is $\lambda$ such that $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$, Thus
\begin{align}
a&=\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}-1\\
b&=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}-\frac{1}{2}\\
c&=\frac{9}{4\lambda^2}-\frac{1}{3}\\
\end{align}
Substitute $a,b,c$ in $g(a,b,c)=0$, then we get
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda^2}=\frac{17}{9}.
$$
But in this case, we find $a <0$, so there is no critical point of $f$ restricted to $g(x,y,z)=0$ in $S$.

Now we will set $c$ as $0$, then
$$
f(a)=\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{3-2a}
$$
and so
$$
f'(a)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-2a}}.
$$
Since $a\ge 0$,
$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-2a}} > 0
$$
and so $f$ increases. Therefore $f(a,b,c)$ has its minimum $2+\sqrt{2}$ at $(1,0,0)$.

**Exercise?:** $f$ restricted to $g(x,y,z)=0$ has its maximum $1+\sqrt{\frac{55}{6}}$.

Comment: The question mentioned that $(1, 0, 0)$ yielded a value of $\sqrt{2}.$

Comment: Let $(a,b,c)=(1,0,0)$, then $\sqrt{a+1}+\sqrt{2b+1}+\sqrt{3c+1}=\sqrt{1+1}+\sqrt{0+1}+\sqrt{0+1}=\sqrt{2}+1+1=\sqrt{2}+2$.

Comment: You are right. The question is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{a + 1} + \sqrt{2b + 1} + \sqrt{3c + 1} - (\sqrt{2} + 2)\\
 =\, & (\sqrt{a + 1} - \sqrt{2}) + (\sqrt{2b + 1} - 1) + (\sqrt{3c + 1} - 1) \\
 =\, & \frac{a - 1}{\sqrt{a + 1} + \sqrt{2}} + \frac{2b}{\sqrt{2b + 1} + 1} + \frac{3c}{\sqrt{3c + 1} + 1}\\
 =\, & \frac{-b - c}{\sqrt{a + 1} + \sqrt{2}} + \frac{2b}{\sqrt{2b + 1} + 1} + \frac{3c}{\sqrt{3c + 1} + 1}\\
 \ge\, & \frac{-b - c}{1 + \sqrt{2}} + \frac{2b}{\sqrt{3} + 1} + \frac{3c}{\sqrt{4} + 1}\\
 =\, & (\sqrt{3} - \sqrt{2})b + (2 - \sqrt{2})c \\
 \ge\, &0.
\end{align*}
Also, if $a = 1, b = c = 0$, then
$\sqrt{a + 1} + \sqrt{2b + 1} + \sqrt{3c + 1} = \sqrt{2} + 2$.

Thus, the minimum of $\sqrt{a + 1} + \sqrt{2b + 1} + \sqrt{3c + 1}$ is $\sqrt{2} + 2$.