# Find the minimum value of

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, karamata-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be reals satisfying:

(i) $a,b,c\ge0$

(ii) $a+b+c=4$

Find the minimum value of the expression

$\sqrt {2a+1}$ $+$ $\sqrt {2b+1}$ $+$ $\sqrt {2c+1}$

So I am literally clueless - I know that the maximum value of the expression can be found by using QM-AM (because the expression is less than or equal to the square root of 3 times the sum of the squares of each term) but I don't know how to find the minimum.

Comment: *Hint:* That is a concave function on a convex domain ...

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693748/find-the-minimum-value-of-sqrta1-sqrt2b1-sqrt3c1-if-abc-1 for a similar question.

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange multipliers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{2x+1}.$

Hence, $f$ is a concave function.

Thus, by Karamata
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{2a+1}\geq f(a+b+c)+2f(0)=3+2\cdot1=5.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** As $ t \mapsto \sqrt t$ is concave, use [Karamata’s inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata's_inequality) with $(a+b+c,0,0) \succeq (a,b,c)$.